# How to fix: “The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.” after malware cleaning

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

few days ago, got hired to optimize a WP site which runs a woocommerce multivendor site. the site was infected by a malware, and cant acces to ftp or cPanel because the owner dont have the credentials to do it, so I search the web and found "Anti-Malware and Brute-Force Security by ELI" plugin. 
after running the scan it put to quarentine the next files:
[image]

I logged out and now that I try to loggin to work other stuff, the message "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.” appear on screen.

The home page is up, but if you click any link, the message will apear again. 
The site is https://heyu.mx

I dont know exactly which plugin uses to make the login, or if it does matter, but cant access to dashboard.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Have you tried contacting their support?

Comment: Without FTP access you are out of luck. If you cannot log in, the first thing to do would be to disable all plugins. To do that without logging in you would need to access the site via FTP and temporarily rename the plugins folder. It sounds strange that a site owner doesn't have credentials to access he's own site... The hosting support could disable the plugins for you as well.

Comment: @kero contacting the support is the fisrt thig I did. Waitng for response.

Comment: @freejack the owner dont have credentials because and agency make the web and they use a hosting for them, so, aparently they dont want to give acces to cpanel. I askes again for ftp access, but still waiting.